# In multiple regression, what is a reasonable minimum size of a group for its dummy variable's coefficient to be reliable?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, statistical-power

Say I am predicting happiness in a sample of college students and my predictors are age, family income, gender, and ethnicity. For my categorical variables (gender and ethnicity), I want to specify ahead of time the minimum number of respondents in a level (e.g., ethnicity = Asian) for me to report that coefficient. For example, if I have an overall sample of 300 respondents and only 2 are Asian, I don't think that dummy variable's coefficient would be reliable and I wouldn't want to report it. If 100 of my 300 respondents were Asian, I'd feel comfortable reporting that coefficient. But where is the cut-off?

Is this something that could be solved with a standard power analysis? For example, if I expect the effect of being Asian vs. my reference group is *d* = .2, would I need n = __ Asian students to report on that level?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no simple way. It depends on effects of your variable of interest both on the outcome as well as your other covariates (age, family income, etc.).

Comment: Do you have any guidance on how one would conduct a "power analysis" for effects like this?

Comment: You can try a simulation approach where you model the data generating process. But, you'll have to make a number of assumptions on how the variables are related to each other.

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2000-16737-004

But that still requires the covariance matrix for all your variables

Comment: Thank you for the article! And yes, I was thinking about a simulation approach. On the whole it seems like there's no simple way to approach this, as you say, but I appreciate the suggestions